# Что такое канонический путь к файлу?

Tags: java, файлы, path

Я изучаю Java и вот что понял относительно разных путей:

Относительный - неполный путь, который существует относительно какой-то директории, например : \data\file.txt
Абсолютный - полный путь, начиная с диска: C:\users\data\file.txt

А что такое канонический путь и зачем он нужен? Я пытался разобраться в англоязычных источниках (плохо знаю английский), но понял только то, что в каноническом пути отсутствуют динамические ссылки (что это?) и вещи вида: ...\ (опять же, что это?).

Разъясните пожалуйста простым языком, что это такое.

Comment: Первая ссылка на английском. К сожалению, английский я почти не знаю, а подробные объяснения я нашёл только на англоязычных сайтах (увы, переводчик не позволяет мне полностью понять смысл канонического пути)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно скажу, я первый раз столкнулся с этим названием. Но первая же ссылка объясняет вот что:
В разных операционных средах (не в винде), есть возможность делать путь к конкретному файлу таким, который в винде не будет работать. Например, в ext4 файловой системе можно сослаться вот так:

\var\some\there\here\where\not\be\..\..\point\file.txt

Это иногда имеет смысл, когда ты делаешь путь с помощью скрипта, который срабатывает из какой-то папки внутри системы и тупо подставляет "..\..\point\file.txt" к пути к текущему подкаталогу.
Но в таком случае путь:

\var\some\there\where\point\file.txt

будет вести к этому же файлу. Так же, как путь:

..\..\point\file.txt тоже будет вести к этому файлу, если ты в

текущий момент находишься в папке:

\var\some\there\here\where\not\be\

Так вот. "Канонический путь" - это тот путь, который будет максимально простым и строгим. "каноничным". То есть, без всех этих странных конструкций. Там же, по ссылке, хороший пример:

absolute path: C:\abc\..\abc\file.txt

canonical path: C:\abc\file.txt

Оба эти пути верны. Но второй является каноничным.
Грубо говоря - пользователи виндоуз всегда пользуются только каноничным путём.

Comment: Вроде всё верно, но винда-то тут при чём? В винде две точки точно так же работают.

Comment: Насколько я помню, в винде не сработает конструкция вида:
C:\Это\Очень\Странный\Путь\..\..\..\Хороший\Путь\

Comment: Кстати, "каноническим" для этого пути будет путь:
 C:\Это\Хороший\Путь\

Comment: Впрочем, я могу ошибаться. Я под линуксом уже давно. И слабо помню, как это в винде работает. Я её только для игрушек держу.

Comment: Вы как-то очень странно помните. Взяли бы и проверили прежде чем глупости писать, раз у вас винда всё-таки есть.

Comment: Ну раз Вы такой умный, взяли бы и написали развёрнутый ответ. Почему же Вы этого не делаете?

Comment: И да, я не мама и не папа. Я помог, пока у меня настроение хорошее было. Если нужно что-то дальше разобрать - всегда есть доки и гугл. Ну и винда под рукой. Тому, кому это реально нужно и интересно - тот может сам провести эксперименты и проверить. Мне это не очень нужно и вообще не интересно. В частности потому, что я не воспринимаю винду как настоящую рабочую среду. Потому что она неудобная для этого, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Спасибо, чуть прояснилось.